# Find all Django model instances with common related model instances (of related model instances)

Tags: django, django-orm

Suppose I have the following models:

```
from django.db import models

class Experiment(models.Model):
    creation_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class Alien(models.Model):
    experiment = models.ForeignKey(Experiment)


class Trial(models.Model):
    experiment = models.ForeignKey(Experiment)
    dosage = models.PositiveIntegerField()


class TrialGroup(models.Model):
    trial = models.ForeignKey(Trial, related_name='groups')
    aliens = models.ManyToManyField(Alien)
    positive_outcome = models.BooleanField()
```

Given a `Trial` instance, how can I create a query to identify all other trials in the same `Experiment` with one or more `Alien`s in common (preferably using the ORM to get back `Trial` instances)?